# Which is good modal popup working code?

Tags: modal-dialog

I would like to have AJAX modal way of pop up box for my website need.  I tried this, http://www.ericmmartin.com/simplemodal-login-released/

It does not work to me well while passing the query strings etc.,

Is there better plugin ?  I found this website, www.bnet.com (click join / log in) ... it looks good.. Is there any plugin to do like this.

My website is mysql and php

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

I use it on a lot of my websites. Easy to implement and simple plug and play with jquery. They are skinnable and with themeroller you can easily mix and match the colors etc to easily implement it within your existing website theme.